# Помогите разобраться с if,else Python

Tags: python, if

Задача---
Тарифный план мобильной связи включает в себя 50 минут разговоров
и 50 смс-сообщений за $15,00 в месяц. Каждая дополнительная минута
стоит $0,25, а каждое дополнительное сообщение – $0,15. Все счета за
телефон включают налог на поддержку кол-центров 911 в размере $0,44,
и общая сумма, включающая сумму отчислений кол-центрам, облагается
налогом в размере 5 %.Напишите программу, которая будет запрашивать у пользователя количество израсходованных за месяц минут разговора и смс-сообщений и отображать
базовую сумму тарификации, сумму за дополнительные мину-ты и сообщения, сумму отчислений кол-центрам 911, налог, а также итоговую сумму к оплате. При этом дополнительные звонки и сообщения необходимо выводить на экран только в случае их расходования. Убедитесь в том,
что все суммы отображаются в формате с двумя знаками после запятой.

Решение :

```
minutes=int(input('Please enter how many minutes did you use this month-> '))
sms=int(input('Please enter how many SMS did you send this month-> '))
payment=15
tax=0.44

if minutes or sms<=50:
        stanart_price=payment+((payment+tax)*0.05)
        print('Tax is for 911 is',tax,'USD')
        print('Total tax is','%.2f'%((payment+tax)*0.05),'USD')
        print('You will pay','%.2f'%stanart_price,'USD')
elif minutes>50:
        add_mins=0.25
        add_sms=0.15
        min_not_in_tafif=minutes-50
        sms_not_in_tafif=sms-50
        add_min_price=((min_not_in_tafif)*add_mins)
        add_sms_price=((sms_not_in_tafif)*add_sms)
        full_price=payment+add_sms_price+add_min_price+((payment+add_sms_price+add_min_price)*0.05)
        print('You basic tarif is 50 min,and 50 sms for',payment,'USD')
        print('Tax is for 911 is',tax,'USD')
        print('Total tax is','%.2f'%((payment+add_sms_price+add_min_price)*0.05),'USD')
        print('You spend additional',min_not_in_tafif,'mins,and addtional',sms_not_in_tafif,'SMS')
        print('Full price is','%.2f'%full_price,'USD')
elif sms>50:
        add_mins=0.25
        add_sms=0.15
        min_not_in_tafif=minutes-50
        sms_not_in_tafif=sms-50
        add_min_price=((min_not_in_tafif)*add_mins)
        add_sms_price=((sms_not_in_tafif)*add_sms)
        full_price=payment+add_sms_price+add_min_price+((payment+add_sms_price+add_min_price)*0.05)
        print('You basic tarif is 50 min,and 50 sms for',payment,'USD')
        print('Tax is for 911 is',tax,'USD')
        print('Total tax is','%.2f'%((payment+add_sms_price+add_min_price)*0.05),'USD')
        print('You spend additional',min_not_in_tafif,'mins,and addtional',sms_not_in_tafif,'SMS')
        print('Full price is','%.2f'%full_price,'USD')
```

Но я никак не могу понять в чем моя ошибка. Например если ввести minutes и sms, менее 50 или 50 все работает отлично, или если ввести оба значения больше - все тоже работает отлично. Но не работает с разноплановыми значениями, если одно ввести 15 а другое 65 то cрабатывает только первый if. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, спасибо!

Comment: @Эникейщик Понял =) , благодарен

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первом `if` у вас написано:

```
minutes or (sms <= 50)
```

оператор `or` выполняется самым  последним, и поэтому у вас идет проверка не равна ли переменная `minutes` 0 или меньше ли `sms` 50.
Если вы хотите что бы у вас было условие - `хотя бы 1 из 2 переменных < 50` то его надо записывать так: `minutes < 50 or sms < 50`. В данный момент у вас было условие `minutes` которое всегда выдавало `True`, если `minutes` не равно 0, поэтому у вас почти всегда выполнялся первый `if`.
Если вы хотите чтобы обе переменные были меньше 50, то условие `minutes < 50 and sms < 50`

Comment: большое спасибо. Но к сожалению, не работает. Или я чего то не понимаю. Сделал так -- if minutes<50 or sms<50: , но если одно значение 51 a другое 18 то срабатывает первый if, и все. Дальше не работает =( А ведь должен уже другой блок выполняться. Ведь одно из значений больше 50. Спасибо!

Comment: Простите немного не понял условия самой задачи. @Oleksandr_I. Тогда надо написать `minutes < 50 and sms < 50`

Comment: большое спасибо! Работает!